# How to use a json data file in iReport Designer 5.6.0

Tags: json, jasper-reports, datasource, ireport

I had just downloaded *iReport 5.6.0*. But unable to load any JSON file parameters on top of the report.

I didn't find any good help online related with this. I find some help from the url as below:-

http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/how-query-file-based-json-datasource

But from the above steps I didn't know where to write query in "report query" and  to manually create fields, matching names of our json data.

Please help to load data from JSON datasource.

Comment: Hope this will helpful for you http://yadavsunny.blogspot.in/2015/04/how-to-generating-table-report-via-json.html

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late, but here are directtions.

1) Click Report Datasource button in iReport Designer:

[image]

2) Click "New", select "JSON datasource, click "Next"

3)  Give it Name, browse to a json file, click "Test" to check:

[image]

json.txt:

```
[
{ "id": 123, "name": "abc" },
{ "id": 456, "name": "def" }
]
```

4) Add fields manually, use proper types and put onto the report page:

[image]

5) Generate preview:

[image]

Comment: At the Report `Report query` window, I could see the Field name but I could not retrieve json data. The path to json file is correct and I'm using json datasource. What should I check?